# ERROR : Conexión android studio con phpMyAdmin

Tags: android, android-studio, phpmyadmin, xampp

Cordial Saludo estimados Desarrolladores, soy muy nuevo en android y en esta oportunidad recurro a ustedes para una ayuda por favor ya que estoy realizando una conexión por PHP desde android studio a phpMyAdmin para que un usuario se logre registrar pero siempre entra en el **onErrorResponse**, he probado mi código desde el software POSTMAN, y efectivamente realiza la conexión y también hace las inserciones sin inconvenientes, agregue la libreria del volley y también el permiso de internet el en manifest, mi código es este:

```
public class RegistroLider extends AppCompatActivity  {

EditText etId, etNomLider;
Button btnCrearLider;
RequestQueue rq;
private static final String TAG = "TAG RegistroLider : ";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro_lider);


    // UI : INTERFAZ USUARIO ----> JAVA
    Log.d(TAG, "InicioVariables");
    etId            = findViewById(R.id.editText_cedula);
    etNomLider      = findViewById(R.id.editText_NombreLider);
    btnCrearLider   = findViewById(R.id.BtnRegLider2);
    rq              = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());


    btnCrearLider.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick");
        CrearLider("http://192.168.0.34:80/elecciones2023/ConexionLideres.php");
    });// FIN : setOnClickListener
}// FIN : onCreate


private void CrearLider(String url) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CrearLider");
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operacion exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
            Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR CONEXION " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("id", etId);
            headers.put("lider", etNomLider);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}}// FIN : Activity RegistroLider
```

adicional adjunto mi archivo de uso para conexión

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    require_once("ConexionDB.php");

    // Creación de variables
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $lider = $_POST['lider'];

    if (empty($id)) {
        exit("El número de Cédula del Lider no puede estar VACIO");
    }

    if (empty($lider)) {
        exit("El nombre del Lider no puede estar VACIO");
    }
    // Envio de query para inserción de datos a tabla lideres
    $query = "INSERT INTO lideres (id, lider) values ('$id','$lider') ";
    $result = $mysql->query($query);

    // Validación de INSERT en la BD
    if ($result == TRUE) {
        echo "LIDER CREADO EXITOSAMENTE";
    }else{
        echo "ERROR AL CREAR EL LIDER";
    }
    // Cierra la conexión a la BD
    $mysql->close();
}
```

De antemano agradezco por su paciencia y amable atención para ayudarme con este inconveniente.

Comment: ¿Qué muestra el mensaje de error? Por otra parte, observa que estás mandando la petición Volley por el método `GET` y en PHP la tratas como si fuera POST.

Comment: Lo mas probable es que el equipo donde estes haciendo las pruebas no este en la misma red de donde tienes montado tu servicio, intenta subiendo tu servicio a un servidor y haciendo la peticion a este y probablemente te funcione

Comment: Hola amigo buen día, gracias por responder, mira el error que arroja es el siguiente com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL http//192.168.0.34/elecciones2023/ConexionLideres.php, lo raro es que el xampp esta funcionando bien, ingresa bien por IP y por localhost y el POST es porque estoy enviando información para que se agregue a una tabla determinada.

El código php hace el envió de los datos y antes de hacerlo hace uso de llamado a otro archivo PHP que hace la conexión, ambos los probé por postman y funcionaron perfectamente.

Comment: Amigo buen dia ya mire que me faltaba algo en la URL pero ya lo corregí y me sale ya es esto com.android.volley.TimeoutError

Comment: El error de Timeout suele ocurrir cuando una petición tarda mucho, agotándose el tiempo de espera. Hay que ver por qué tarda. En primer lugar prueba la URL directamente en el navegador y dinos si funciona. Y revisa el log de errores de ese servidor.

Comment: Que tal amigo buen dia, si efectivamente si funciona ingresando directamente desde el navegador inclusive hasta he probado los archivos PHP desde Postman y funcionan perfectamente, hace conexión, inserta y todo sin problema pero no se si es que me falta algo desde android que arroja error.